# Getting private posts from Google+ using APIs

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-plus

I worked with facebook graph API.
With a Facebook application I was able to retrieve user information (e.g. posts, status update, and so on) using graph APIs. Of course, it can be possible only for users that accept to share their information with the application.
I'm going to do the same with Google+. First of all I want to say that I'm new in the google+ universe.
Reading Google+ documentation I'm aware about the possibility to fetch public posts using something described here:
https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search?hl=en
Of course, here they talk only about "public activities".

Does exist on Google+ a similar mechanism to Facebook application that allows me to retrieve private posts from a user (after that he approves my application of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently available.

You may wish to star (and thus follow) [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=928) to indicate you would like to see this as a feature and to track progress or responses from Google.